# AudioWorkletProcessor and Polymer 3.4.1 and 'window' not defined

Tags: polymer, audioworkletprocessor

Trying to use lit element/Polymer Web components AND an Audioworklet/AudioWorklet processor, I got this error:

```
boot-c9e09360.js:20 Uncaught ReferenceError: window is not defined
at boot-c9e09360.js:20:1
```

at this line in my code:

```
await aw.audioContext.audioWorklet.addModule("micSpkrAwp.js") //micSpkrAwp is the audio-worklet-processor running in different process.
```

The boot-c9e09360.js is a polymer file that contains:

```
/**
```

@license
Copyright (c) 2017 The Polymer Project Authors. All rights reserved.
...
*/

/* eslint-disable no-unused-vars */
/**

- When using Closure Compiler, JSCompiler_renameProperty(property, object) is replaced by the munged name for object[property]
- We cannot alias this function, so we have to use a small shim that has the same behavior when not compiling.
- 
- @param {?} prop Property name
- @param {*} obj Reference object
- @return {string} Potentially renamed property name
  */
  window.JSCompiler_renameProperty = function(prop, obj) {
  return prop;
  };

I have been using lit element/Polymer web components and it works well. I removed the polymer components and the AudioWorkletProcessor works well.
I think that the problem is that Polymer assumes that window is defined (since polymer works with DOM), but when encountering a javascript file - the AudioWorkletProcessor which has no reference to DOM (just a file that provides the audio process interface) this error occurs.
Any suggestions?
Code of micSpkrAwp.js:

import { frameBufferQBRes } from "./queue.js"
import {config} from "./config.js"

class MicSpkrProcessor extends AudioWorkletProcessor {

```
constructor() {
    super()
/** ..**/


process (inputs, outputs, parameters){
      console.log(`micSpkrAws - this.stopImmediateFlag ${this.stopImmediateFlag}`)
      if (this.stopImmediateFlag) return false
      const retVal=this.processFromQueue(inputs,outputs,parameters)
      return retVal
    }
  }
  registerProcessor('mic-spkr-processor', MicSpkrProcessor)
```

Comment: What's the content of `micSpkrAwp.js`? Why do you want to include polymer in an AudioWorklet?

Comment: micSpkrAwp.js is an AudioWorkletProcessor(has a process function to process audio as per https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioWorkletProcessor and is just a javascript file: I am including polymer to build the normal user interface  components - text boxes, dropdowns etc. Not in AudioWorklet.  The AudioWorklet is part of my app. The issue is that I cannot make polymer UI, and AudioWorklet work together, because Polymer appears to make the JsCompiler require the 'window' which is not available when the AudioWorkletProcessor (micSpkrAwp.js in my case) is processed. code above.

Comment: Please show the content of that js file. If it complains that `window` is undefined it means that the polymer scripts got injected in the Worklet. For this to happen given the code you shown, it must be from that script.

Comment: Apologies..The original code  was too long, and I posted only parts of it.  Will work on a minimalist version and post that entirely if problem persists (or post the resolution if not).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Kaiido for the solution!
Answer: Polymer scripts got injected into the AudioWorkletProcessor code due to importing :

```
import { calculateSplices } from '@polymer/polymer/lib/utils/array-splice';
```

This was not immediately visible since it was a nested import (imported file contained this import statement). This import was removed, and the problem solved!